# MVC4 Web-API - Route mapping help required

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api-routing

i have a controller named

**Products**
and i have three actions in it

- **Product** : *takes an int returns a model(class) object*
- **Category** : *takes a string returns array of model(class) object*
- **All** : *no parameters return array of model(class) object*

what i was trying was the following mapping

**Product** ->  api / products / product / 1

**Category** -> api / product / category / sauces

**All** -> api / product / all

as the names of action support the URL structure so i was trying a general route which is

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

all else is working but i am getting the following error when i use this `http://localhost:2271/api/products/category/2` URL

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:2271/api/products/category/2'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'Products' that matches the request.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

on the other hand this URL `api/products/category/?cat=abc` & `api/products/category?cat=abc` is working fiine...... [cat is my receiving parameter name]

help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> on the other hand this URL api/products/category/?cat=abc &
>   api/products/category?cat=abc is working fiine

Yes that's right, it will, and that's the RPC style of doing it. If you want to maintain the RESTful way of doing it you can have the following route configuration:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ProductById",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ProductByCategory",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/category/{cat}"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultByAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { action = "Get" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And your controller will look something like this:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    // api/products/
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };            
    }

    // api/products/5
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "Product" + id;
    }

    // api/products/category/fruits
    [HttpGet]
    public string Category(string cat)
    {
        return "Product " + cat;
    }    
}
```

NOTE: I returned strings for simplicity's sake but I assume you will return an instance of a `Product`, and you can easily change the code to do so.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, could you please specify for this particular how it was not maintaining RESTful manner, i am new to REST APIs..

Comment: Glad to help. I think [a link to a well-written article is better](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restful#RESTful_web_APIs). There's a mention there about RPC. There are other documentations that explains it better but I have to Google them :)